# Why are some images not being showed on page load while some are?

Tags: html, image, flash

On my website, images are not loading for some pages. The website is in flash. The address can be found at http://www.serenityspacharleston.com

More specifically, when you go to "Our Spa" or "Location" pages, the images show up, but on the other two pages, it only shows a percentage, as if the pictures were loading, but they never complete.

I verified the XML file and all links for the images are pointing to the correct placement, as far as I can tell (they are using the same format as the links that do work). Any thoughts on why some images would not be showing up? I can provide the source code if that is helpful.

Comment: Adding the specific parts of the code that you think are causing the issue would indeed be of help to us. Also share with us what changes you've already tried and didn't work out. Thanks.

Comment: You have to verify your images URLs because your server is returning a 404 response for those files?